# Can't open collection in the MongoDB shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I can 't open a collection in the MongoDB command prompt. I can add users, update users, get users via Postman etc...

The first time this happened was a few months ago by deleting a user. First there was nothing to show with db.database.find(). But after restarting my local Windows10 machine it worked again. But now restarting even not works. I think open the collection [the proper way](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#working-with-the-mongo-shell). Any ideas?

```js
MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/
MongoDB server version: 3.4.6
> show dbs
admin    0.000GB
user  0.000GB
local    0.000GB
> use user
switched to db user
> show collections

profiles
users
> use users
switched to db users
> db.users.find()

// then nothing happens anymore
```

Comment: Perform the exact same sequence of commands but without the last `use users` command. `use` selects a database, not a collection. The breakdown of `db.users.find()` is `db` refers to the selected database (in this case `user`), and `users` a collection in the selected db, and `find` is the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're switching to db `users` you have no db called `users` just don't use `use users` and just use `db.users.find()`

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/
MongoDB server version: 3.4.6
> show dbs
admin    0.000GB
user  0.000GB
local    0.000GB
> show collections

profiles
users


> db.users.find()
```

The use command is for databases so you should't use it to checkout a collection.